# Launching GUI apps from GNU screen on OS X

Tags: macos, gnu-screen

On OS X 10.9.1, when I try to launch GUI Apps on OS X from within a GNU screen terminal, the app simply hangs without showing a window. Launching the same app from a regular terminal outside screen works fine.

```
Laptop:/Users/ambarish> /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
```

Nothing at all. No window, and no response to even Ctrl-C.

I can kill TextEdit from another terminal, and then I get

```
Terminated: 15
Laptop:/Users/ambarish>
```

I'm an OS X n00b, and am switching from Linux; what am I doing wrong? Should I have to set an env variable, similar to $DISPLAY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To launch "native applications" on MacOS, don't try to identify and run their "main binary". Instead, use the magic "open" command:

```
open /Applications/TextEdit.app
```

Should do what you want from any terminal, screen or no.